# Determine if outlet is truly 20A

Tags: outlet

My breaker panel shows the island and wall receptacles (two separate breakers) in my kitchen have 20A breakers. I noticed the outlets do not have the "T" shaped plug, making me think they are possibly 15A outlets. Is there a way to reliably determine if they are 20A rated? I'm guessing I should probably just pull the cover and try to determine what gauge the wire is.

Comment: I assumed you are in North America.. :) since you mentioned T shaped plug for 20A

Comment: Voltage drop at full load (or at any load with scaling) is a good indicator. At full load, if it varies slowly and in a consistent direction with time, turn it off and look for a fire extinguisher :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a 20A circuit, according to the breaker panel.

The NEC (National Electrical Code) article 210-21-B-3 has a table in it that allows for 15A duplex outlets on a 20A branch circuit that has one or more duplex outlets on it or more than 1 single outlet.

That outlet is 15A rated, but the circuit will be 20A rated, and it will have multiple outlets on the same circuit.

Comment: So i should be fine running ~17A without upgrading the outlets (and continuing with 12ga wire)? I'll keep an eye on the voltage as mentioned above.

Comment: 17A total on multiple outlets, yes, you should be fine. But any single outlet is still only 15A rated.

Comment: Yeah, and even if each outlet is rated for 15A total you would be advised to avoid running them steady state at that current level. The recommendation would be to keep the steady state load at 80% of the 15A max.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: I was under the impression that all US outlets are required to be capable of carrying 20 amps without overheating (which would imply that 15 amps continuous duty should be no problem) because they are approved for installation in circuits where the upstream protection device is set for 20 amps rather than 15.  The difference between 15A and 20A outlets is that the former are designed to discourage the use of 20A appliances.